# Django - ImportError: cannot import name Celery

Tags: django, celery, importerror

It is the first time I use celery, I went through this tutorial: [Using celery with Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)
but when I run the code it gives me the following error :

```
from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
```

What is wrong ? 
Thank you

Comment: Did you install celery like `pip install celery`?

Comment: @zaidfazil , yes I did

Comment: python and django version?

Comment: @zaidfazil, python 2.7 , celery==4.0.2 and Django==1.11.3

Comment: DO you have any file name `celery.py`? I think that may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Install `celery` and add `celery.py` in your project directory.

Comment: @zaidfazil , yes I have proj/proj/celery.py that contains the configuration of celery as mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your in folder `celery.py` to something else like `_celery.py`, then try the import. It should work. The error is because the your `celery.py` file clashes with the `celery` module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it:

```
pip install celery
```

Comment: if you use virtualenv, make sure that you activated it !

Answer (score 0):

If celery is already installed, I guess you installed in in virtualenv and when you run the project, you didn't activate the virtualenv (or vice versa). One more case is that I think you typed the wrong directory of the celery package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this line of code in the top of your file.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
```

Then you should be fine and does not need to change the name of your file.